# Why does git svn init create an empty repository?

Tags: git, osx-snow-leopard, git-svn

i am trying to follow [this guide](http://www.jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/) in order to move a project from svn to git. i don't particularly care about merging things upstream so this seems like the cleanest solution of those i've explored.

my issue is that when i execute `git svn init file:///Users/Ankur/path/to/repository --no-metadata`

i get the message `Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Ankur/path/to/repository/.git/` which is supposed to be the first line of the output anyway, but its supposed to be followed by individual messages about commits. i don't get anything else (and this executes pretty quickly).

i've verified the path that i am using is correct by doing `svn co file:///Users/Ankur/path/to/repository` with the same repository to make sure i can checkout the repository normally.

details about my system: Mac OS X 10.6.5, `which git` returns `/usr/bin/git` (which i think means it was installed with Xcode because i removed the version i got with the git-osx-installer thinking it might have been the culprit initially). `git --version` returns
`git version 1.7.2.3`

Comment: Do you intend to run `git svn clone` instead? `init` just creates an empty repository.

Comment: as per instructions in the guide i want to follow this with a `git svn fetch` but the reason i think its separated as two steps is so that i can do the `svn.authorsfile` and `--no-metadata` steps in there.

Comment: So what's the problem? Does the `git svn fetch` work?

Comment: oh. my. god. u're right. i forgot that all the action of checking in/out the revisions happens after the call to `git svn fetch`. thanks very much for clearing that up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a git repository:

`git svn init` is analogous to `git init` or `svnadmin create`. They both create empty repos.

`git svn clone` is analogous to `git clone` or `svn checkout`. They both make copies of remote repos.

Comment: according to [http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html] `git svn clone` is actually running two commands: `git svn init` followed by `git svn fetch`, which is precisely my intention using the guide i linked to.

Comment: the comments up top on my question clarifies my problem. thanks and im sorry for asking a confusing/trick question!